# Can I export salesforce SOQL query data in json format from jiterbit data loader?

Tags: salesforce, crm, jitterbit

I tried to get salesforce opportunity data in JSON file format from jitterbit data loader. I received  json file, but, when I open it, I can see it like a csv file.
Can you please someone suggest me, is it possible to export json file format for salesforce data from jitter data loader?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, the Data Loader only supports flat file formats. See the [datasheet](https://marketrepo.jitterbit.com/Content/DS_DataLoaderVSIpaasComparison_EN.pdf).